# CREATE TABLE `table` AS SELECT with ignore?

Tags: mysql

**QUESTION** - Is there an equivalent to INSERT IGNORE for when it comes to CREATE TABLE AS?

Trying to run a rather complex and large query which takes 10-15mins to run, then save the results into a fresh table for the reporting systems.

Only I keep hitting walls

Ultimately, I want to refresh the destination table every time I run the query, there are ~80 columns and these change regularly. So we have been dropping the table and recreating based on the results.

My problem is I keep hitting data formatting issues in the creation, I can run the query happily but it doesn't like it when I want to save the results into the newly created table. Works well with small quantities with a 10 limit, but when I raise the quantities I throws errors which I want to ignore

ie  1292 - Truncated incorrect time value: '2499:38:34'

**Follow up Question**

Or is there a way of using INSERT without having to specify each field / type in a similar way that CREATE TABLE AS works?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
CREATE TABLE `table`  AS 

SELECT (
... * Complex query *
)
```

Comment: Then I have to specify the columns with the insert, I am unsure sure what the columns are going to be in a weeks time

Comment: Or I break it up into 2 phases

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `email_stats_daily_rollup`;
CREATE TABLE `email_stats_daily_rollup`  AS 
SELECT (
... * Complex query *
Limit 10
)
 -- Phase 2 of query

TRUNCATE TABLE `email_stats_daily_rollup`;
INSERT IGNORE `email_stats_daily_rollup`
SELECT (
... * Complex query *
)
-- 
Only I am at a risk of the limit 10 being subject to a Truncated incorrect time value issue, which breaks the automation

Comment: Limit is not the issue. With a create table as select mysql tries to guess the datatypes from a subset of rows and sometimes gets it wrong. Why are you doing it this way - are the number of columns returned by your query variable or are they the same every time?

Comment: What do you mean by 'there are approximately 80 columns that change regularly', because this sounds a lot like poor design

Answer (score 0):

You could use the keyword `IGNORE`:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (PRIMAY KEY (key_field)) AS
IGNORE SELECT key_field, field_1, field_2
FROM source_table;
```